# Algorithm for Finding a possible profit

Tags: algorithm

I 'm searching for an algorithm (and except the naive  brute force solution had no luck) that efficiently (O(n^2) preferably) does the following:

Supposing I’m playing a game and in this game I’ll have to answer n questions (each question from a different category). For each category “i”  i=1,...,n  I’ve calculated the probability  p_i  to give a correct answer.

For each consecutive k correct answers I’m getting  k^4 points. What is the expected average profit?

I will clarify what I mean by expected profit in the following example:

In the case n=3 and  p_1=0.2,p_2=0.3,p_3=0.4

The expected profit is

EP= (0.2* 0.3* 0.4 )3^4+  (I get all 3 answers correct)

- (0.2* 0.3* 0.6 )2^4+ (0.8* 0.3* 0.4 )2^4+ (0.2* 0.7* 0.4  )2+  (2 answers correct)
- 0.2* 0.7* 0.6 ) + (0.8* 0.3* 0.6 )+ (0.8*0.7* 0.4 ) (1 answer correct)

  clearly for each possible outcome I'm calculating the probability and multiply it with the points gained. And then get the sum off all those.

Any ideas?
I'm only interested in the sum itself.

Thank you!

Comment: I find your post very hard to read, most likely due to your unfamiliarilty with markdown. I suggest you review your post (using the preview) with the "code" feature and edit it for readability.

Comment: I can't seem to get this done. I can type mathematical expressions here right?

Comment: If you mean MathJax, nope - only on math.stackexchange, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Anif: Not that I'm aware of.  The best you can do is use the "code" mode to get a different font.

Comment: I think it's bit better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `A[t]` be the expected profit after `t` questions given that either `t = 0`, `t = n`, or the `t`'th question was answered wrong.  Then you can compute

`A[0] = 0`

`A[t]` = sum(i = 0..t-1) (probability of getting questions `i` .. `t-2` right and `t-1` wrong) * ((`t-i-1`)<sup>4</sup> + A[i]) when `0 < t < n`.

`A[n]` is computed similarly to the general case above, except you should also add a term for when all questions after the `i`th are answered correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. How will you compute A[1] using your formula?

Comment: Unless `n = 1`, `A[1] = 0`.  `A[1]` is the expected profit after one question conditioned on the first question being answered wrong.

Comment: But why are we assuming that the first question is answered wrong? and then isn't A[2] zero also?

Comment: Put another way, `A[i]` captures all possible strings over "R" and "W" that end in "W" and have length `i`.  So `A[1]` represents just "W", while `A[2]` represents "WW" and "RW" and `A[3]` represents "WWW", "RWW", "RRW", and "WRW."  Wrong answers let us cleanly decompose the string into the score before the wrong answer plus the score after the wrong answer.  I clarified the answer.